# How to access google sheet's data using Python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to access the contents that is in Google Docs or Spreadsheets. I'm using the link that is generated when I click 'Get Shareable link' in Google docs.

I'm only able to scrap login page's data when I use :

```
import requests 
r = requests.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/e/abcdef12345_sample/edit?usp=sharing", auth=('user', 'pass'));
print(r.content)
```

But I want to scrap the contents that are inside the spreadsheet/document.
Note : MFA is enabled for my account.

How can I achieve that? Should I use any other kind of authentication other than basic auth?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have already obtained the access token by following the OAuth 2 authentication process, you can use the following function I've written to pull the data from your google sheet into a pandas dataframe.

This method leverages the python requests module and avoids the recommended packages from Google.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

def get_google_sheet_df(headers: dict, google_sheet_id: str, sheet_name: str, _range: str):
    """_range is in A1 notation (i.e. A:I gives all rows for columns A to I)"""

    url = f'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{google_sheet_id}/values/{sheet_name}!{_range}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    values = r.json()['values']
    df = pd.DataFrame(values[1:])
    df.columns = values[0]
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
    return df

headers = {'authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
           'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'}

google_sheet_id = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
sheet_name = 'Class Data'
sample_range = 'A:F'

df = get_google_sheet_df(headers, google_sheet_id, sheet_name, sample_range)
```

You can test it on the google_sheet_id provided in this example, all you need is your access token.

[image: google sheets pull example]

Answer (score -1):

There's a python library called [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), install using `pip install gspread`

You also need to get **OAuth2** credentials from Google using [Google's developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). All the information you need is in the **gspread** docs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20881872)

Comment: @Rob, edited with a bit more information, hope that's better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google Sheets API.

The steps are [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

1. Turn on Google Sheets API
2. Install the Google Client Library
3. Create a file called `quickstart.py`. Make sure you change the SPREADSHEET_ID. To find your spreadsheet id, check its URL. It is after /d/.

   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=sheetId

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   from googleapiclient.discovery import build
   from httplib2 import Http
   from oauth2client import file, client, tools

   # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
   SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'

   # The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
   SPREADSHEET_ID = 'spreadsheetId'
   RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'


   def main():
   """Show basic usage of Sheets API. 
      Print items in sheets. 
   """
       store = file.Storage('token.json')
       creds = store.get()
       if not creds or creds.invalid:
           flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
           creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
       service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

       # Call the Sheets API
       SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
       RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
       result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
           spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
           range=RANGE_NAME).execute()

       values = result.get('values', [])
       if not values:
           print('No data found.')
       else:
           print('Name, Major:')
       for row in values:
           # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
           print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
4. Run quickstart.py
5. Enjoy the API!

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, as OP is asking how to access google sheet's data using Python requests module